# Laravel 5.5. Many-to-Many. Receive the latest instance

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-5.5

I have such models (Many-to-Many)

```php
class Driver
{
    public function cars()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Car::class);
    }
}
class Car
{
    public function drivers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Driver::class);
    }
}
```

My Car has `activated_at` column, that can be `null`.

How can I retrieve the latest activated car per drivers in a specific parking?

Something like this

`Parking::find(2)->drivers()->lastActivatedCars...`?

Comment: do you want a list of all drivers with the car they activated last? Or the last activated car among all drivers

Comment: Yes, I want a list of all drivers with _the car they activated last_ property

Comment: What about drivers without an activated car? Should they be included in the result?

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a scope for the car.

```
// Car.php
public function scopeActivated($query)
{
    return $query->whereNotNull('activated_at')->orderBy('activated_at', 'DESC');
}
```

And then in your Driver.php:

```
// Driver.php

public function latestActivatedCar()
{
    return $this->cars()->activated()->first();
}
```

Then you can just:

```
$latest = $driver->latestActivatedCar();
```

Or you can create a relationship, so you can eager load.

```
// Driver.php

public function latestActivatedCar()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Car::class)
                ->whereNotNull('activated_at')
                ->orderBy('activated_at', 'DESC')
                ->limit(1);
}
```

Then you can just:

```
$drivers = Parking::find(2)->drivers;
$drivers->load('latestActivatedCar');
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would help:

```html
Parking::with(['drivers' => function ($driverQuery) {
    $driverQuery->with(['cars' => function ($carsQuery) {
        $carsQuery->orderBy('activated', 'desc')
            ->limit(1);
    }]);
}])->find(2);
```